# ¿Cómo sincronizo una carpeta que acabo de crear con Github?

Tags: git, github

Tengo un proyecto conectado a github. Creé una nueva carpeta en el projecto y quiero sincronizarla con Github. ¿Cómo lo hago?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con el comando `git add .`
Haces el commit con `git commit -m "mensaje de commit"`
y luego haces push a tu master o main

`git add` Sirve para agregar todos los archivos del working directory al staging area, también podrías usar `git add <file>` si solo quieres agregar un archivo

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco para que sirve `git add`, sino que mejor usé una interfaz gráfica para git.

Comment: `git add .` sirve para agregar todos los archivos del working directory al staging area, también podrías usar `git add <file>` si solo quieres agregar un archivo